# (iOS) GCM silent push notification to trigger calling another API when app is terminated

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I need help on how to get notification for chat app when the application is terminated.

I'm using GCM for silent push notification. It works when the app is in foreground or background because when the silent push notification comes, it will trigger the app to call the chat API to get the message and schedule the local notification to show the notification bar with the message.

I'm using this to send silent push:

```js
{
  "content_available": true,
  "registration_ids": ["device_token"]
}
```

But how to handle when the app is terminated? I've read articles saying that it's not possible. My chat app is not VoIP app. Any workaround how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OS won't start a terminated app if a silent push is sent to it, unless as you have read, its a VOIP push.

So what you could do is first of all send a silent push to your app and when the app receives it to send an acknowledgement to the server.
If your server doesn't receive an acknowledgement it could send a foreground push that looks identical from the user's perspective to the local notification your app is posting when it receives the background push.